FastAPI & AsyncIO & Threding & Beanie
I want to write a FastAPI application that works with Kafka and MongoDB. The idea is as follows: I run an application that provides an API to store something in MongoDB and publish events to Kafka. Then I wait for an event from Kafka and update the existing record. I use the Aiokafka library. I do not want to run Kafka's listener in the same event loop where my app works. So I decided to spawn a new thread where I run a new asyncio loop that should update a record. Here's my approach:

error occurred. Details: Task <Task pending name='Task-8'
coro=<run_async_task..wrapper() running at
fastApiMicroServices/proj/app/core/background.py:15>
cb=[run_until_complete..done_cb()]> got Future <Future pending
cb=[_chain_future.._call_check_cancel() at
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/futures.py:387]>
attached to a different loop

async def lifespan(application: FastAPI):
    logger = setup_root_logger()

    client = await init()
    session = await client.start_session()

    start_background_task(create_and_run_consumer, session=session, logger=logger)

    async with create_producer() as kafka_producer:
        application.producer = kafka_producer
        yield

Where
async def init() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient(str(settings.MONGO_DB_URI), serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000)
    await init_beanie(database=getattr(client, settings.MONGO_DB_NAME), document_models=gather_documents())

    return client

And:
def start_background_task(coroutine, **kwargs):
    thread = threading.Thread(
        target=run_async_task,
        args=(coroutine,),
        kwargs=kwargs
    )
    thread.start()

    return thread

And
def run_async_task(coroutine, **kwargs):
    logger = kwargs.get('logger')
    loop = None

    async def wrapper():
        try:
            if 'session' not in kwargs:
                kwargs['session'] = get_session()
            await coroutine(**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error in background task: {e}")

    try:
        # loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        # asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        # loop.run_until_complete(wrapper())
        asyncio.run(wrapper())
    finally:
        if loop:
            loop.close()

And:
async def create_and_run_consumer(**kwargs):
    consumer = None
    logger = kwargs.get('logger')
    session = kwargs.get('session')

    try:
        consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
            settings.CONSUMER_TOPIC,
            bootstrap_servers=settings.KAFKA_DSN.split(','),
            group_id=settings.CONSUMER_GROUP)
        await consumer.start()

        logger.info('CONSUMER THREAD: Kafka consumer has started.')

        async for msg in consumer:
            logger.info(f'CONSUMER THREAD: consumed event for [{msg.key}] with payload: [{msg.value}]')
            payload = json.loads(msg.value)
            await Entity.find_one(Entity == msg.partition, session=session).update(Set({Entity.objects: payload['objects']}))

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'CONSUMER THREAD: error occurred. Details: {str(e)}')
    finally:
        logger.info('CONSUMER THREAD: Kafka consumer has been closed.')

        if consumer:
            await consumer.stop()

How can I use Beanie in the separate event loop?
